# Adding Image using javascript

Tags: extension

I am trying to insert a new image using an extension and I am put that image into images directory (under the extension directory);

```
CRM.$(function($){
   cj("#civicrm-menu").prepend('<li class="menumain"><span class="menumain-label"><img src=""></img></span></li>');
});
```

> I tried to put like this

```
src ="images/myimg.png"
```

But it is not working.

How to give a src path of that image ?

Answer (score 0):

I looked in `CRM.config` to see if there was a helpful variable, but there isn't.  I think you need to add this variable via PHP.

From the [CiviCRM Javascript Reference](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/standards/javascript/#server-side-variables) on Server-Side Variables:

In PHP:

```
$config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addVars('myNamespace', array('extensionsUrl' => $config->extensionsURL));
```

In JS:

```
src = CRM.vars.myNamespace.extensionsUrl + "/images/myimg.png"
```

Comment: I tried but not working.

Comment: @deepak Without knowing what's not working about it, it's very hard to suggest a solution.  Can you print the variable with `console.log`?

Comment: http://localhost/copy/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/images/myimg.png . Here extension name is missing.

Comment: so can't you just add the extension name ?

Comment: '$imgPath = E::url('images\myimg.png');' I used this code for getting an image path and it is working but when I clicked on any contact of activity or group tab then it appends so many time. I put this code in preProcess() method.